# use a transaction database to calculate the probability of an item appearing in a future transaction using R or SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r, database

I have a database of transactions like in the table below

```
   user_id order_id    order_number                 product_name     n
   <int>    <int>           <int>                       <fctr>     <int>
    1      11878590           3                       Pistachios     1
    1      11878590           3                           Soda       1
    1      12878790           4                           Yogurt     1
    1      12878790           4                  Cheddar Popcorn     1
    1      12878790           4            Cinnamon Toast Crunch     1
    2      12878791           11          Milk Chocolate Almonds     1
    2      12878791           11                     Half & Half     1
    2      12878791           11                   String Cheese     1
    11     12878792           19                      Whole Milk     1
    11     12878792           19                      Pistachios     1
    11     12878792           19                            Soda     1
    11     12878792           19               Paper Towel Rolls     1
```

The table has multiple users who each have multiple transactions. Some users only have 3 transactions, other users have 15, etc. This is all in one table.

I'm trying to calculate a transition matrix for a markov model. I want to find the probability that an item will be in a new basket given that it was present in the previous basket of transactions.

I want my final table to look something like this

```
user_id    product_name   probability_present    probability_absent
   1            Soda              .5                    .5
   1             Pistachios       .5                    .5
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the data into a form so that I can calculate the probabilities and specifically coming up with a way to compare all of the t,t-1 combinations.

I have code that I've written to get things into this form, but I'm stuck at this point. I've written my code using the dplyr R package, but I could translate something in SQL into the R code. I can post my code in R if it will be helpful, but it is pretty simple at this point as I just had to do a few joins to get the table into this shape.

What else do I have to do to get the table/values that I'm trying to calculate?

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make sense. User 1 has never bought soda or pistachios. You should be able to manually calculate sensible output for such a small data set. Edit your question, and include a) sensible output, and b) how you calculated it.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I'll change the products just to clear up any confusion, but the examples that I posted was just to show the structure of the table and the output table that I showed was just to show the structure of the output that I'm trying to get. The actual table that I'm working with has millions of rows. This was just a very small sample to show how everything is structured. Also, in this example User 1 didn't buy soda in transaction 4, but they could have bought soda in transaction 3. I want to calculate probabilities over the lifetime of all transactions that I have.

Comment: Yes, it shows the structure, but it does not show how to compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to give you the desired probabilities:

```
SELECT user_id,
       product_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) / COUNT(*) AS prob_present,
       1 - COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) / COUNT(*) AS prob_absent
    FROM tbl
    WHERE user_id = 1
    GROUP BY user_id, product_name;
```

Or at least it gives you the numbers you have.  If this is not right, please provide a slightly more complex example dataset.

Comment: That just means that they got enough the first time to last til the next time.  If we are now at 15, and he has not bought any since 11, seems like there is a high prob that he will buy now.  Looking at 'consecutive' transactions is much more complex.

Comment: I think `COUNT(*)` is not correct here. You probably need a subquery like `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) FROM tbl WHERE user_id = 1)` or a JOIN with a derived table.